# Algorithm - Calculating user rating from number of posts and comments

Tags: php, algorithm, variables

I'm developing a small PHP script that calculates a ratio for the users in my publishing platform.

This ratio should be calculated using these two variables that I have ready:

`$user_comment_count` = The user's total comment count

`$user_post_count` = The user's total article count.

To keep a solid ratio, the user needs 2 comments per article. So, if the user has published 5 articles and 10 comments, then the user's ratio would be `1.00`. If 5 posts and 15 comments, then `1.50`. The lowest ratio that the user can have is `0.00` and there should be no limit set on highest.

How do I make this calculation in PHP using these two variables?

Comment: can you give an explanation on how the ratio is going to be interpreted? For example, "how active this user is" or "how responsive this user is". Otherwise, I can't come up with a sensible calculation for exceptional cases like: very high number of comments with 1-0 post or very high number of posts with 1-0 comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ratio = $user_comment_count / max(1, $user_post_count * 2);
```

This will also work, though the first solution is probably more readable:

```
$ratio = $user_comment_count / ($user_post_count * 2 || 1);
```

Comment: Excellent, can you please elaborate on your answer. I wish to learn how it functions. What happens if post_count/comment_count equals 0? how does the `max` work here?...

Comment: @HenrikPetterson:  [`max()`](http://php.net/max) returns the greatest value that was passed to it.   If post count equals 0,  the `max` function will return `1`. All other valid values of post count will cause the function to return `$user_post_count * 2`.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Max gives you the highest number of the items being compared. In this case, if $user_post_count is less than 0.5, it will still output 1. For example, if $user_comment_count was 10, and $user_post_count was less than 0.5 (not sure why it ever would be), the ratio would be 10

Comment: This is a stellar answer Tim, thank you. One final question before I accept this as correct. Is there any difference in your two solutions beside that one is more readable?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson:  The second solution runs about 2x faster (on my computer) when doing 1,000,000 iterations all at once.  So if you're looking to micro-optimize, use that one.

Comment: @TimCooper Thank you for taking the extra step to make that test. Optimisation is essential for this script, I assure you. Cheers again Tim!

Answer (score 3):

Most obvious solution:

```
$ratio = ($user_comment_count)/(2*$user_post_count);
```

Thinking more deeply:

[1]
Ok, you probably want to reward both posting and commenting.
So the the ratio needs to go up monotonically with both post count and comment count.
Hence, the above solution is not satisfying this.

[2] You kind of want the user to have **at least** 2 comment per post otherwise the user will be punished.

So the new solution would be:

```
function base_score($user_post_count, $user_comment_count) {
    return $alpha*$user_post_count + $beta*$user_comment_count;
}

function score($user_post_count, $user_comment_count) {
    if (($user_comment_count >= 2*$user_post_count) || ($user_post_count = 0)) {
        return base_score($user_post_count, $user_comment_count);
    }else {
        $deficit = $user_comment_count / (2.0*$user_post_count);
        return base_score($user_post_count, $user_comment_count)*$deficit;
    }
}
```

So the more `$user_comment_count` missing from `2*$user_post_count`, the more actual score will scale down.

`$alpha` and `$beta` are the importance factor of post count and comment count respectively. subject to:

```
0 <= alpha, beta
```

Comment: And if their post count is 0?

Comment: @TimCooper Can you offer an alternative solution?

Comment: probably if statement. anyway, I just answered what is the most obvious. I'm still figuring out what this 'ratio' is supposed to reflect and used.

Comment: @Billiska Please feel free to update your answer with a working solution.

Comment: add `$` to the php variables

Comment: Please add `$` to your variables and format your IF statement correctly with `;` at the right places etc This is a great answer otherwise.

Comment: Um... I'm sorry, but could you add that yourself? I haven't programmed in PHP in years. :P Think of it as I'm answering you in pseudocode, even though what I'm writing is actually Python.

Comment: I completely understand, but what I am trying to do here is to give you credit for an awesome attempt of writing a great answer. The problem with it is that the code is not in PHP language, making the solution incorrect even though the calculation may be correct. So users that will come here will not benefit from your answer, note that this is tagged PHP. This is a shame as I can see what you are trying to do and I can certainly see how it is beneficial. If you could kindly rewrite your Python code into a working PHP code, then I would be more than happy to mark this answer as correct.

Comment: You can probably tell I came here from the algorithm tag. ;) Once you go Python, PHP just looks unreadable. I kind of want to get my algorithm across rather, because to me that is what is most important.